# convex figure in Machine learning

Tags: machine-learning

I am learning ML from the past few days and I stuck in the gradient descent convex figure. From which values, the convex figure is drawn to apply gradient descent. Is that convex figure is made from hypothesis and cost function algorithms??

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming

Comment: OP, for future reference, questions like this should go on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com)